# HLS stream HTML5 video - refresh after buffering for X time

Tags: html, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I have a simple site with an HLS stream from a m3u8 playlist in an autoplay video tag. If the stream stops for more than 10s or so it will not "catch up" and start again when the stream is restarted - I need to manually refresh the page to get it to play again.

Is there a way with js (or something else) to automatically refresh the page after the video has been buffering for X time? (say 5 seconds)

Comment: **(1)** Yes it's possible to [reload a page](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+reload+page) so now you need an `IF` statement to decide when to reload. **(2)** Find a way to get your [**video events**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+detect+video+event) (you must detect "buffering" state and start a timer). **(3)**  Maybe instead of refreshing the whole page you could just write a Javascript function to re-set the `src` of your video tag and then also re-load the tag (to apply a new setting). Example `myVid.src = your_path_here; myVid.load();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @VC.One I'll have a look at detecting video events, this looks like something I can work with! Thanks a lot for setting me in the right direction, this is the piece I was missing. Good idea on resetting the `src`, I'll have a go.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this with some help from VC.One's answer. This will reload after the video has been buffering for 5 seconds, if the video was previously playing. Otherwise it will be stuck in a reload loop if it never starts playing. I am still looking for a way to check whether the stream is live without actually reloading the page. `video.load()` and `video.play()` are giving me errors, but I will update this post when I figure it out.

```
var reloadCheck;
var reloadThisTime;
var video = document.getElementById("videotag");
var sourcetag = document.getElementById("sourcetag");
video.addEventListener('waiting', (event) => {
  console.log("No connection");
  reloadCheck = setTimeout(function(){
    if(reloadThisTime){
      location = '';
    };
  },5000);
});

video.addEventListener('playing', (event) => {
  console.log("Connected");
  clearTimeout(reloadCheck);
  reloadThisTime = true;
});
```